# Parse a html file without Beautiful soup

Tags: python, html

I have a .html saved on my disk and I open with a text editor. Then I try to find all the http ....etc where are on the html file.

I open, read the file but how can I mention with for loop that "Hey give me all the hyperlinks after the href= ?"

Any suggestion? I try to solve it without Beautiful soup.

Comment: `grep 'href' file.html`?

Comment: What's wrong with BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Nothing! But the instructor said no with this kind of solution! ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful Soup makes parsing websites so easy, because the whole "regular expression part" (and some other things...) are already done for you.
So in order to solve the problem without Beautiful Soup, you have to do that part on your own. A simple but effective way would be using re.findall() or re.search() as follows:

```
import re

links = []
with open("htmlcode.txt", "r") as file:

    for line in file.readlines():

        match = re.search(r"href=\"(.+)\">", line)

        if match:
            links.append(match.group(1))
```

Where `r"href=\"(.+)\">"` is the pattern the line is scanned for. I don't know if that is what your looking for, but anything even more basic would just be a waste of time. If you have

- questions about the code don't hesitate to ask
- want to know more about regex (regular expressions) follow the [IntroductionLink](https://scotch.io/tutorials/an-introduction-to-regex-in-python) or the python [software foundation website](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/regex.html)

Comment: Thank yo Wenn for your kind answer. I am trying to find not all the table of an html file, but only the information incudes inside the "href" and the "title" from the html file. Now I am trying to understand the regular expression and then I hope to find a solution. Furthermore could you please explain to me what does it means the 'r' character before the href (  re.search(r"href=\"(.+)\">", line)  ) ? Thank you again! :)